# Backslashes being treated as escape character Python/Json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am running an object detection model(Darknet Yolov4), and piping it's outputs to a `results.json` file. However, every time i run it in the `"filename"` field a single backlash is used, which python is viewing as an escape character. Does anybody know how I might fix this problem?

The Command Line Code I am running:

```py
 cmd = f"darknet.exe detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov4_test.cfg custom-yolov4-detector_best.weights -dont_show -ext_output -out result.json {path}"
```

The Json File:

```
[
{
 "frame_id":1, 
 "filename":"C:\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\darknet\\x64\\f047.png", 
 "objects": [ 
  {"class_id":32, "name":"right", "relative_coordinates":{"center_x":0.831927, "center_y":0.202225, "width":0.418463, "height":0.034752}, "confidence":0.976091}, 
  {"class_id":19, "name":"h", "relative_coordinates":{"center_x":0.014761, "center_y":0.873551, "width":0.041723, "height":0.070544}, "confidence":0.484339}, 
  {"class_id":24, "name":"left", "relative_coordinates":{"center_x":0.285694, "center_y":0.200752, "width":0.619584, "height":0.032149}, "confidence":0.646595}, 
  {"class_id":11, "name":"a", "relative_coordinates":{"center_x":0.094595, "center_y":0.488480, "width":0.089853, "height":0.046685}, "confidence":0.978590}, 
  {"class_id":12, "name":"b", "relative_coordinates":{"center_x":0.075972, "center_y":0.534347, "width":0.096545, "height":0.043278}, "confidence":0.930176}, 
 ] 
}
]
```

Python Code(For Identification

```py
def identify(path):
    cmd = f"darknet.exe detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov4_test.cfg custom-yolov4-detector_best.weights -dont_show -ext_output -out result.json {path}"
    # cmd = f"darknet.exe detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov4-tiny-custom.cfg custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_best.weights -ext_output -out result.json {path}"
    
    os.chdir(r'C:\Yolo_v4\darknet\build\darknet\x64')    
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.stdout.read()
    print(out)

identify(r'C:\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\darknet\\x64\\f047.png')
```

Comment: Use an `r` prefix or use double backslashes.

Comment: The result.json file is automatically updated every time I run the code, which would have to be every ~30 seconds on my robot where this code will be used. I can't manually change it every time

Comment: Can you show the code where you use backslashes? I see only forward slashes in your code snippet.

Comment: Where is the `filename` field?

Comment: @pavel I added the Json code, my bad

Comment: @Barmar I added the json code

Comment: Backslashes are escape characters in JSON. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: That JSON file looks fine to me.

Comment: The question says the filename field has a single backslash, but it looks like all the backslashes are doubled, which is the proper thing to do.

Comment: @Barmar look at the slash after `build`

Comment: Is `"filename"` passed in as `{path}`.  Show a [mcve] with how you set `path`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen No, path is the path to the image we are running through the model

Comment: The `.png` file?  Show your Python code.

Comment: Change this line to: `identify(r'C:\Yolo_v4\darknet\build\darknet\x64\f047.png')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslash`(\)` by itself in JSON, it's **considered an escape characther**, it like others.
Therefore, these must be written in a particular way **to be used in strings**:

In your case the backslash must be replaced with `\\`

in your code, at the following line:

```
"C:\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\darknet\\x64\\f047.png"
```

at `build\darknet` you're using only one backslash, so JSON consider it a character escape.

the right code should be:

```
"C:\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64\\f047.png"
```

See also [how other special characthers are escaped in strings](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html) (it's also a online tool for making your JSON escaping tests).

Comment: The result.json file is automatically updated every time I run the code, which would have to be every ~30 seconds on my robot where this code will be used. I can't manually change it every time

Comment: You don't need to change the result.json file. You need to change the Python script. Fix the argument to `identify()`.